# Selenium- "Waiting for xxxx"- Chrome

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Website I am testing needs to load libraries from `xxxx` server.

Sometimes it takes to long and website display information `Waiting for xxxx` (I am using Chrome WebDriver).

Is it possible to treat it as an error and catch it using Selenium?

Comment: I'm not sure what language you're using, but all of the bindings as far as I know have a **WebDriverWait** object where you can wait for whatever you want and give it a timeout. Once the timeout is reached, it will throw an error. In short, the answer is yes, use **WebDriverWait**.

Comment: But will I get a detailed error with name of a link which takes too long?

Comment: Yes, if you program it that way. **WebDriverWait** is pretty customizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes when it takes to long and you see website display information **`Waiting for xxxx`** it is not actually an error. It means the the **`JavaScripts`** and the **`AJAX Calls`** associated with the Website are getting executed while the `Page Loads`. Once the `JS` & `AJAX Calls` gets executed completely, the Page Loading completes.

Now as per your question `Is it possible to treat it as an error and catch it?` the Answer is **`Yes`**.

This can be achieved by using the **`pageLoadTimeout`** method which **`Sets the amount of time to wait for a page load to complete before throwing an error.`**

Defined as **`pageLoadTimeout(long time, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit unit)`**, an example will be as follows :

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The error thrown is as follows :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timeout loading page after 2000ms
```

You can find a detailed  implementation of **`pageLoadTimeout`** in [**`pageLoadTimeout in Selenium not working`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591282/pageloadtimeout-in-selenium-not-working/45648881#45648881) discussion.

Comment: But can I get a link which took to long to get to?

Comment: Generally, its the `JavaScripts` and the `AJAX Calls` which gets executed. You can always get to know the `JavaScripts` and the `AJAX Calls` which gets executed in the `HTML DOM` through a query.