# PhantomJS is not returning errors when URL is wrong (python)

Tags: python, linux, selenium-webdriver, error-handling, phantomjs

I am using selenium in python, especially PhantomJS
the problem is when I send a wrong URL, no error happens
while firefox driver catch an error

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, 
NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("drr,.gh")
```

I want to know how my program can recognize a false URL

This is my first post here so I apologize if I made an error, I also apologize for my English

Thank you

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. You mean that want to recognize a wrong URL even before the driver tries to navigate to it? Or do you expect an exception but not getting one?

Comment: I am expecting an exception, I want my script to throw an exception when the driver is handling a wrong URL

Answer (score 0):

When we provide a **`Malformed URL`** as an argument to **`get()`** method through **`GeckoDriver`** or **`ChromeDriver`** we do see a proper exception shows as :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Malformed URL: drr,.gh is not a valid URL.
```

But when providing the **`Malformed URL`** as an argument to **`get()`** method through **`PhantomJSDriver`** from the logs it seems the validation of a proper formatted `URL` is missing and **`PhantomJSDriver`** keeps on attempting to browse to the `URL` which it never succeeds which is as follows :

```
[INFO  - 2017-12-14T08:13:37.981Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 2585
[INFO  - 2017-12-14T08:13:39.482Z] Session [b0debdb0-e0a6-11e7-ad4b-79a57b4a1a11] - page.settings - {"XSSAuditingEnabled":false,"javascriptCanCloseWindows":true,"javascriptCanOpenWindows":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"loadImages":true,"localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled":false,"userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/2.1.1 Safari/538.1","webSecurityEnabled":true}
[INFO  - 2017-12-14T08:13:39.482Z] Session [b0debdb0-e0a6-11e7-ad4b-79a57b4a1a11] - page.customHeaders:  - {}
[INFO  - 2017-12-14T08:13:39.482Z] Session [b0debdb0-e0a6-11e7-ad4b-79a57b4a1a11] - Session.negotiatedCapabilities - {"browserName":"phantomjs","version":"2.1.1","driverName":"ghostdriver","driverVersion":"1.2.0","platform":"windows-8-32bit","javascriptEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"handlesAlerts":false,"databaseEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"browserConnectionEnabled":false,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"webStorageEnabled":false,"rotatable":false,"acceptSslCerts":false,"nativeEvents":true,"proxy":{"proxyType":"direct"}}
[INFO  - 2017-12-14T08:13:39.482Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _postNewSessionCommand - New Session Created: b0debdb0-e0a6-11e7-ad4b-79a57b4a1a11
```

### Solution :

As a solution, we can generalize the passing of **`Malformed URL`** as an argument to **`get()`** method as an **`Unreachable Destination`** and you can induce the **`set_page_load_timeout(seconds)`** as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'C:\\Utility\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe')
driver.set_page_load_timeout(2)
driver.get("drr,.gh")
```

In the event of **`page_load_timeout`** occuring you would see the following log messages :

```
[ERROR - 2017-12-14T08:25:43.994Z] RouterReqHand - _handle.error - {"name":"Missing Command Parameter","message":"{\"headers\":{\"Accept\":\"application/json\",\"Accept-Encoding\":\"identity\",\"Connection\":\"close\",\"Content-Length\":\"71\",\"Content-Type\":\"application/json;charset=UTF-8\",\"Host\":\"127.0.0.1:2650\",\"User-Agent\":\"Python http auth\"},\"httpVersion\":\"1.1\",\"method\":\"POST\",\"post\":\"{\\\"pageLoad\\\": 2000, \\\"sessionId\\\": \\\"60b5bc60-e0a8-11e7-bb6f-8df56dd28746\\\"}\",\"url\":\"/timeouts\",\"urlParsed\":{\"anchor\":\"\",\"query\":\"\",\"file\":\"timeouts\",\"directory\":\"/\",\"path\":\"/timeouts\",\"relative\":\"/timeouts\",\"port\":\"\",\"host\":\"\",\"password\":\"\",\"user\":\"\",\"userInfo\":\"\",\"authority\":\"\",\"protocol\":\"\",\"source\":\"/timeouts\",\"queryKey\":{},\"chunks\":[\"timeouts\"]},\"urlOriginal\":\"/session/60b5bc60-e0a8-11e7-bb6f-8df56dd28746/timeouts\"}","line":546,"sourceURL":"phantomjs://code/session_request_handler.js","stack":"_postTimeout@phantomjs://code/session_request_handler.js:546:73\n_handle@phantomjs://code/session_request_handler.js:148:25\n_reroute@phantomjs://code/request_handler.js:61:20\n_handle@phantomjs://code/router_request_handler.js:78:46"}

  phantomjs://platform/console++.js:263 in error
```

You can find a detailed discussion on [**`set_page_load_timeout()`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47694922/how-to-set-the-timeout-of-driver-get-for-python-selenium-3-8-0/47695227#47695227) method here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the information, but it didn't solve my problem, I noticed that when I give a wrong URL, the driver doesn't take a long time with it,  actually, with this solution, some legit URLs have errors now, especially the ones that take time to completely load

Comment: So your Question, **PhantomJS is not returning errors (python)** is solved now. Please **`Accept`** the **`Answer`** by clicking on the tick mark beside my answer, just below VoteDown arrow so the tick mark turns reen. But again, each application needs some `Benchmarks`, e.g. **page_load_time**. `Page Loading` shouldn't be a never ending process. Configure a `time_out` for the Page Loading process e.g. **driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)**. The working one will load whilest the Malformed one will time_out. See the link to the detailed discussion within the Answer.

Comment: **set_page_load_timeout** doesn't solve my problem. Because the driver handles the bad URL so quickly, I am not sure but it seems like the driver just ignores it. As for my question I must admit that I didn't choose the right title, it's not that Phantom doesn't  return errors, but rather it doesn't return the error that I want so you didn't solve my problem ^^, it is my mistake and I apologize for the misunderstanding