# Overriding Python Selenium WebDriver.get() to catch TimeoutException

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using Python Selenium with Chromedriver. Every once in a while, a `webdriver.get()` call will throw a `TimeoutException`. I'm successfully catching every other exception through explicit waits, but the `TimeoutException` seems to occur when the network stream gets dropped.

What I want to do is modify the `webdriver.get()` method (through overrides or subclassing) so that every time my application calls `get()`, it will automatically:

- Catch and handle `TimeoutException`
- Retry the `get()` request a few times

How do I accomplish this?

**Note**: This question is not a duplicate of [How to set the timeout of 'driver.get' for python selenium 3.8.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47694922/how-to-set-the-timeout-of-driver-get-for-python-selenium-3-8-0) -- I'm trying to add implicit functionality to the get() method. The reason I don't just wrap my get() calls in a try/except block manually is because I'm making a lot of them througout my application and am attempting to be DRY.

Comment: @DebanjanB This does not look look like a duplicate of this question. While the content of that question would certainly help, it is not what the question asks.

Comment: why not try/catch the .get() call?

Comment: @DebanjanB it's not a dupe. See my edit.

Comment: @pcalkins I added some info about that. I'm making a lot of get() calls.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way is to do a try/except and make the except only catch the TimeOutException

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
try:
    webdriver.get(url)
except TimeoutException:
    time.sleep(5)
    webdriver.get(url)
```

If the problem is that you have to do this several times encapsulate it in a method

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You have to subclass `EventFiringWebDriver` like this:

```
from selenium.support.events import EventFiringWebDriver

class MyWebDriver(EventFiringWebDriver):
    def get( self ,url):
        try:
            super().get(url)
        except TimeoutException:
            # your exception handling code goes here
```