# How to stop test if page taking too long to load in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, pageloadtimeout, pageloadstrategy

I'm testing a website and all is good with me except when the page is taking too much time then selenium keeps on searching for the element. I've tried to use `driver.set_page_load_timeout(5)` but still keeps on loading forever.
Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import *
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time, os,re, datetime
import logging




class SanityTest():

def login_test(self):
    driver_location = 'C:\\chromedriver.exe'
    os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = driver_location
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_location)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(0)
    baseURL = driver.get("https://www.example.com/")
    logging.basicConfig( format = '%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s',datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'
                        ,level=logging.INFO)
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(2)

    #Is Platform is reachable?:-
    try:
        if WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class,'button')]"))):
            logging.info("Success")
    except:
        pass

    try:
        if WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[@jsselect="heading" and @jsvalues=".innerHTML:msg"]'))):

            logging.error('Failure: Unable to reach platform! ==> ' + str(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@jsselect="heading" and @jsvalues=".innerHTML:msg"]').text))
            return
    except :
        print("Page is taking too long to load")
        return



 ff = SanityTest()
 ff.login_test()
```

Answer (score 0):

Functionally `set_page_load_timeout()` works and should have worked for you:

```
driver.set_page_load_timeout(2)
```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [How to set the timeout of 'driver.get' for python selenium 3.8.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47694922/how-to-set-the-timeout-of-driver-get-for-python-selenium-3-8-0/47695227#47695227)

However it is worth to mention that `set_page_load_timeout()` is applicable only after **'document.readyState'** is equal to **`"complete"`** is achieved. Perhaps in this usecase `'document.readyState'` equals to `"complete"` is achieved pretty late.

---

### Solution

As a solution instead of using the default `pageLoadStrategy` which is by default set to **`normal`**, you can set `pageLoadStrategy` as **`eager`** i.e. **interactive** as follows:

```
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "eager"  #  interactive
```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [How to make Selenium not wait till full page load, which has a slow script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770796/how-to-make-selenium-not-wait-till-full-page-load-which-has-a-slow-script/44771628#44771628)