# How to force Selenium to refresh if the website takes too much time to load

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, pageloadtimeout

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
browser = webdriver.Edge()

st1 = time.time()
browser.get("http://app1.helwan.edu.eg/Commerce/HasasnUpMlist.asp")
et1 = time.time()
el1 = et1-st1
print(f"Elapsed Time is: {el1} Seconds")
# 10.48

st2 = time.time()
my_id = browser.find_element("name","x_st_settingno")
submitting = browser.find_element("name","Submit")
my_id.send_keys(18760)
submitting.click()
et2 = time.time()
el2 = et2-st2

link_to_natega = browser.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="ewlistmain"]/tbody/tr[3]/td[9]/font/b/span/a')
link_to_natega.click()
```

This works just fine. The problem is at `el1`. I tried making it a function to refresh using `browser.refresh()` when `if el1>=10`

But it turned out as I may have understood from the articles is that `el1` is being calculated after the code is done. I want it to measure the loading time in real-time and keep updating the number so that I could keep track of and then refresh the page if the condition is met.

To state the problem clearly:

1. The program will try to get to "http://app1.helwan.edu.eg/Commerce/HasasnUpMlist.asp"
2. If it takes more than 10 seconds doing so, refresh(), else continue the code
3. If `el2` also is greater than `10`, go back to the original URL "http://app1.helwan.edu.eg/Commerce/HasasnUpMlist.asp" and do the code again.

Comment: you can set page load timeout in the webdriver (driver.manage)... and try/catch exceptions on the .get() call to re-do if timeout is caught.  After a .get() Selenium will wait for a ready state before running anything else.  (If timeout period is reached it throws timeout exception.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To restrict the [page load time](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.set_page_load_timeout) to ***10 seconds*** you can use the [*`set_page_load_timeout()`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47695227/7429447) method as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
browser.set_page_load_timeout(10)
while True:
    try :
        browser.get("http://app1.helwan.edu.eg/Commerce/HasasnUpMlist.asp")
        print("URL successfully Accessed")
        # continue with the next steps
    except TimeoutException as e:
        print("Page load Timeout Occurred. Refreshing !!!")
        browser.refresh()
```