# Webdriver wait not throwing timeout exception

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, timeout, webdriverwait

> Hi, I am trying to use webdriver in selenium test. I want to check how it works. I given 5 seconds as maximum time in webdriver wait. My page loading time is more than 7 seconds but I am still not getting any timeout exception from webdriver wait. I am giving my console output also. Please tell why i am not getting timeout exception?

```
public class MainClass {

private static ChromeDriver driver;


public static void main(String[] args) {



            executeTest();

}

private static void executeTest( )  {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");

    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    // driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.get("http://myUrl");

    Long loadtime = (Long) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
            .executeScript("return performance.timing.loadEventEnd - performance.timing.navigationStart;");

    System.out.println("loadding time " + Loadtime);

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);

    Boolean sign_in = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("signinbutton")))
            .isDisplayed();

    if (sign_in == true) {
        driver.findElement(By.id("signinbutton")).click();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Oops! Couldn't locate sign_in element!");
    }

    Boolean user_name = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("username_id")))
            .isDisplayed();
    // user_name.sendKeys("ANAND@RIL");
    if (user_name == true) {
        driver.findElement(By.id("username_id")).sendKeys("ANAND@RIL");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Oops! Couldn't locate user_name element!");
    }

    Boolean password = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("password_id")))
            .isDisplayed();

    if (password == true) {
        driver.findElement(By.id("password_id")).sendKeys("ANAND");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Oops! Couldn't locate password element!");
    }

    WebElement login = 
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("textButton")));
    login.click();

}
}
```

Console ooutput:

Attempt 1 :

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91) on port 42020
Only local connections are allowed.
Apr 18, 2018 12:07:35 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
**Loading time 7872**
```

Attempt 2 :

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91) on port 38325
Only local connections are allowed.
Apr 18, 2018 12:07:46 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
**Loadding time 6632**
```

Attempt 3 :

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91) on port 34619
Only local connections are allowed.
Apr 18, 2018 12:07:55 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
**Loadding time 7522**
```

Attempt 4 :

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91) on port 48000
Only local connections are allowed.
Apr 18, 2018 12:08:05 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
```

Comment: Try with try-catch. In under catch, use 'throw' statement.

Comment: where i have to put try catch

Comment: @learner Which line of code are you expecting the error? There is a difference between selenium loading the page and webdriverwait...

Comment: i am expecting timeout exception in sign_in button code..bcoz sometime my initial url take more than 60 seconds to load ..after load initial URL first page contains sign in button..

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the method with a try-catch. Please try the below thing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
try{
    executeTest();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        throw e;
    }
}
private static void executeTest( ) throws Exception {
try{

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");

    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    // driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);

    driver.get("http://myUrl");

    Boolean sign_in = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("signinbutton")))
            .isDisplayed();

    Long loadtime = (Long) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
            .executeScript("return performance.timing.loadEventEnd - performance.timing.navigationStart;");

    System.out.println("loadding time " + Loadtime);

    if (sign_in == true) {
        driver.findElement(By.id("signinbutton")).click();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Oops! Couldn't locate sign_in element!");
    }

    Boolean user_name = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("username_id")))
            .isDisplayed();
    // user_name.sendKeys("ANAND@RIL");
    if (user_name == true) {
        driver.findElement(By.id("username_id")).sendKeys("ANAND@RIL");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Oops! Couldn't locate user_name element!");
    }

    Boolean password = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("password_id")))
            .isDisplayed();

    if (password == true) {
        driver.findElement(By.id("password_id")).sendKeys("ANAND");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Oops! Couldn't locate password element!");
    }

    WebElement login = 
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("textButton")));
    login.click();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: tried as u said,but not getting any eception,just showing loading time only .still loading time above 7 seconds

Comment: Please try the changed. I just declared wait before `driver.get()`.

Comment: still not getting any exceptions,,last loading times are "loadding time 7842,loadding time 9983"..

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider a few facts as follows :

- [**`pageLoadTimeout()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#pageLoadTimeout-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) : `pageLoadTimeout()` sets the amount of time to wait for a page load to completely before throwing an exception/error. If the timeout is negative, page loads can be indefinite.

  In your code you have configured `pageLoadTimeout()` to **40** seconds. As per the logs your page loading times are **7872 ms**, **6632 ms** and **7522 ms**, so you don't see an exception/error.

  If you don't configure the `pageLoadTimeout()`, as per the current implementation of *GeckoDriver* the default value of **"pageLoad":300000** is considered.

  You can find a detailed discussion on *pageLoadTimeout()* in [**pageLoadTimeout in Selenium not working**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591282/pageloadtimeout-in-selenium-not-working)
- [**`WebDriverWait()`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) : `WebDriverWait()` is the specialization of [FluentWait](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html) that uses WebDriver instances and works in-conjunction with the [**ExpectedConditions**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) Class which is defined to wait for a certain condition to occur before proceeding further in the code.

  In your code you have configured `WebDriverWait` to **5** seconds which is applicable to all the *ExpectedConditions* you have used as :

  ```
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("signinbutton")));
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("username_id")));
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("password_id")));
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("textButton")));
  ```

  All the *ExpectedConditions* are achieved within the time span of **5** seconds. So you don't see any exception/error either.

  You can find a detailed discussion on *WebDriverWait / ExplicitWait* in [**Replace implicit wait with explicit wait (selenium webdriver & java)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45712431/replace-implicit-wait-with-explicit-wait-selenium-webdriver-java/45715759#45715759)

Comment: but in my code pageLoadTimeout() is commented,i am not using that code..and when i giver webdriver wait 1 second ,at that time also am not getting any exceptions..

Comment: Updated my answer _If you don't configure the `pageLoadTimeout()`, as per the current implementation of GeckoDriver, the default value of **"pageLoad":300000** is considered_

Comment: k.can u say in webdriver wait when i given 1 second,at that time also i didnt get any exception..i tired many test runs..and loading elemets taken more than 1 second,den also it didnt throw any exception.so am confused

Comment: A lot depends on the architecture of the _AUT (Application under Test)_. If the app is based on _HTML5_ normally all the elements will be loaded when the _WebClient_ achieves `'document.readyState' is equal to "complete"` but incase of _Angular_ or _React Native_ based apps _WebDriverWait()_ plays a vital role. In your case _WebDriverWait()_ may be trivial but definitely it's a good practice to move forward.