# How to make selenium to reload the desired url if it takes too long loading

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, pageloadtimeout

I want selenium to force the browser to reload the page which it is loading if the loading process takes too long.

From StackOverflow I have that this code

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until((ExpectedCondition<Boolean>) wd -> ((JavascriptExecutor) wd)
                .executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
```

will wait until the page is fully loaded, but I want it to be reloaded if it takes more than 30 seconds.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: there is a PageLoadTimeout:  https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html

Comment: Just to clarify, this WebDriverWait method is for client-side page updates.  For full page loads from the server, PageLoadTimeout comes into play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reload the webpage incase the loading process is taking too long you can configure [pageLoadTimeout](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#pageLoadTimeout-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-). `pageLoadTimeout` sets the amount of time to wait for a page load to complete before throwing an error. If the timeout is negative, page loads can be indefinite.

An example (using Selenium v3.141.59 and GeckoDriver v0.24.0):

- Code Block:

  ```
  public class pageLoadTimeout 
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
          WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
          driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          try{
            driver.get("https://www.booking.com/hotel/in/the-taj-mahal-palace-tower.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaGyIAQGYATG4AQbIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKSAgF5qAID;sid=338ad58d8e83c71e6aa78c67a2996616;dest_id=-2092174;dest_type=city;dist=0;group_adults=2;hip_dst=1;hpos=1;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;srfid=ccd41231d2f37b82d695970f081412152a59586aX1;srpvid=c71751e539ea01ce;type=total;ucfs=1&#hotelTmpl");
            // do your other work here
          }catch(WebDriverException e){
            System.out.println("WebDriverException occured");
            }
          driver.quit();
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  1565680787633   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\Debanjan.B\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.3jw3aiyfNAiQ"
  1565680826515   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 56499
  1565680827329   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
  Aug 13, 2019 12:50:28 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
  INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
  Aug 13, 2019 12:50:31 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes toStatus
  WebDriverException occured
  ```
- You can find a relevant discussion in [pageLoadTimeout in Selenium not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591282/pageloadtimeout-in-selenium-not-working/45648881#45648881)

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Do we have any generic function to check if page has completely loaded in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50327132/do-we-have-any-generic-funtion-to-check-if-page-has-completely-loaded-in-seleniu/50329056#50329056)

Answer (score 1):

`WebDriverWait` with through timeout exception. Put your code inside `try/catch` and reload the page on timeout exception:

```
try {
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until((ExpectedCondition<Boolean>) wd -> ((JavascriptExecutor) wd)
            .executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    // log a timeout
    // System.out.println("Page load timeout, refresh.");
    driver.navigate().refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `_driver.Navigate().Refresh()`;