# Unable to catch TimeOutException from pageLoadTimeout and refresh page using selenium Java FireFox Driver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, timeoutexception, pageloadtimeout

I have an issue with Selenium Firefox Driver where sometimes a google ad of some kind gets stuck loading. I can get by this by simply clicking the refresh button and the page will fully load, I can read the data I need and move onto the next page. If I don't manually click refresh it will eventually timeout with the default timeout time but this takes a few minutes.

This of course isn't ideal and I was hoping that I could handle this scenario automatically.

I tried manually changing the timeout time and adding a Try Catch block as can be seen below

```
    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    FixturesDataStore fixtures = new FixturesDataStore();
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    for(int i = 0; i < fixtures.getHomeTeams().size(); i++)
    {
        try
        {
        driver.navigate().to(FORMURL.concat( (fixtures.getHomeTeams().get(i)).replace( ' ', '+' )));
        }catch(WebDriverException e)
        {
            System.out.println("What a catch!!");
            driver.navigate().refresh();
        }
```

The error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timeout loading page after 10000ms
```

It highlights the line

```
driver.navigate().refresh();
```

as causing the error.

Comment: 10000ms is 10s... how do you get from 10s timeout to "but this takes a few minutes"?

Comment: "If I don't manually click refresh it will eventually timeout with the default timeout time but this takes a few minutes." That was prior to me setting the timeout time hence the word default. I was setting the scene as to what was happening and what I was trying to accomplish. If you read on I clearly state that I tried manually changing the timeout time as part of my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is pretty much as expected and as per the specifications.

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timeout loading page after 10000ms
```

...is the result of `pageLoadTimeout()` which you have configured as:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

For a detailed analysis about the reason for the exception you can always catch the **WebDriverException**. You can find a detailed discussion in [pageLoadTimeout in Selenium not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591282/pageloadtimeout-in-selenium-not-working/45648881#45648881).

---

### Outro

[How to make selenium to reload the desired url if it takes too long loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57468213/how-to-make-selenium-to-reload-the-desired-url-if-it-takes-too-long-loading/57473031#57473031)