# How to close the chrome browser right after 20 seconds handling the exception errors?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, timeoutexception, pageloadtimeout

I am using this code with ChromeDriver and Chrome browser:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20));
Thread.sleep(20000);
driver.quit();
```

Then  webpage keeps loading more than 20 seconds and closing with `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException`

But its not working.

Comment: `driver.manage().timeouts().` says how long will the driver wait. Not what to do after the wait time. Btw what's the point of closing browser (or driver) after insufficient wait time?

Comment: @pburgr I want chrome to close after **20** seconds, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException;

driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20));
try {
    driver.get("https://www.amazon.com");
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
//  e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Quitting...");
    driver.quit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20))` method sets the maximum amount of time the driver should wait for a page load to complete before timing out. This means that if a page takes longer than 20 seconds to load, the driver will throw a `TimeoutException` and stop waiting for the page to load. However, this method does not close the browser automatically after 20 seconds, it only sets the page load timeout.

The `driver.quit()` method is used to close the browser and end the WebDriver session. But the `driver.quit()` method is not affected by the page load timeout and it will close the browser immediately after it is called, regardless of how long the page has been loading.

So, if you want to close the browser after 20 seconds, you need to use the `Thread.sleep(20000)` method, which will pause the execution of the program for 20 seconds, before calling the `driver.quit()` method.

You could use a combination of both methods, by setting the page load timeout and then waiting for 20 seconds before closing the browser.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20));
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
Thread.sleep(20000);
driver.quit();
```

Alternatively, you could use a Timer and TimerTask to close the browser after a specific time like this:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
...
 driver.get("https://www.google.com");

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               driver.quit();
               timer.cancel();
           }
        }, 20000);
```

Comment: I tried your code, but stills page keeps loading more than 20 seconds and closing with **java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException**

Comment: It's showing this error: This method schedule(TimerTask, long) in the type Timer is not applicable for arguments(new TimerTask(){}, int)

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation [*pageLoadTimeout*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#pageLoadTimeout(java.time.Duration))

> Sets the amount of time to wait for a page load to complete before throwing an error. If the timeout is negative, not null, or greater than 2e16 - 1, an error code with invalid argument will be returned.

So [*pageLoadTimeout*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591282/pageloadtimeout-in-selenium-not-working/45648881#45648881) is effective when the page is loading is *In Progress*. If the page loading takes more time *TimeoutException* is raised.

Example snippet:

```
public class pageLoadTimeoutJava {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(2));
        try {
            driver.get("https://www.booking.com/hotel/in/the-taj-mahal-palace-tower.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaGyIAQGYATG4AQbIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKSAgF5qAID;sid=338ad58d8e83c71e6aa78c67a2996616;dest_id=-2092174;dest_type=city;dist=0;group_adults=2;hip_dst=1;hpos=1;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;srfid=ccd41231d2f37b82d695970f081412152a59586aX1;srpvid=c71751e539ea01ce;type=total;ucfs=1&#hotelTmpl");
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            System.out.println("pageLoadTimeout occured");
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer still stands but marking @AbiSaran answer because he posted earlier.

Comment: @KarenM You are welcome to mark any of the answer which suits best to you. All the best.

Answer (score -1):

Press Ctrl + Alt + Delete. Click Task manager​. Under 'Processes', look for 'Google Chrome' or 'chrome.exe'. Click it, then click End process.

Comment: This is selenium not windows.

Comment: A poor answer. Read the question properly before answering, and take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer